# Facebook API - Have to Refresh

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using the Facebook API to try and implement a login.

My problem is that when I load the page in-browser by typing XXXXXXX and hitting enter, the page loads but instead of the Facebook Login button rendering, the words "Login to Facebook" are displayed instead. The button doesn't render, and I don't see any Javascript errors.

However, when I hit CTRL + R, the button **does** load instead.

I'm shortly going to re-write the whole PHP, AJAX and Javascript code anyway and make it much nicer (a view controller, security conscientious code etc), however for when I do, can someone please help me identify the reasons for the problem described above so I can avoid this the next time around.

Steps to reproduce this error:

1. XXXXXXX - *in a browser that isn't logged in to Facebook*
2. Note the button doesn't load
3. Refresh the page
4. Note the button does load

Also, I'd also like to point out that I just tried the steps again and had to refresh multiple times to get the button to render. XXXXXX seems to work well however, I think the code is pretty much identical as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be loading fine on my end, using Chrome, ie, FF and safari.  I would first suggest clearing your cache.  Also you can use async loading of the sdk, then fbml parse to render button after sdk loads...

---

```
      <div id="loginbutton"></div>
      <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
    appId  : 'yourAppId',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    //channelUrl : 'http://WWW.MYDOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });
    // using xfbml parse in async to render button after sdk is download and init.
    Cbuild1 = document.getElementById('loginbutton');
    Cbuild1.innerHTML = "<fb:login-button></fb:login-button>";
setTimeout("FB.XFBML.parse(Cbuild1)", 1100);
    //
      };
      (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol +
          '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
      }());
</script>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Already using async loading, however in IE it does look like when I delete the browser cache and THEN load the page everything seems to work. Anything I can put in there to prevent the user having to delete the cache every time?

Comment: did you add the fbml.parse to the async?  It will prevent the button from trying to render before the sdk is downloaded, or pulled from cache on a harddisk that may need defragged.  Or wrap the button in a function, and call the function from within the async.

Comment: I did, nothing seems to have changed adding those three lines.

Comment: did the button load?  If not this might be a local issue with your own browser.  As i said before, your button is loading fine for me, in 4 different browsers, even if i refresh over and over.

Comment: With the button correctly loaded I can hit enter in the address bar and the page loads only the text. When I hit refresh instead the button does indeed load. Problem is I can go on my iPhone browser and load the page and the button loads intermittently there also, albeit the success is a lot less frequent. Therefore possibly a timing issue?

Comment: ok i take that back, it did fail one time in IE9.   Use a set timeout. of about 1100ms.  ill edit into my answer.

Comment: It is diffidently a timing issue.  I would remove the jquery for the moment and use only the async sdk with xfbml parse.  or async load your jquery before the fb.sdk.  Seems facebook is ready before jquery.

Comment: After a bit of tinkering, it does seems like a timing issue. Your time-out code with fbml.parse works great and this appears to be the issue I was having. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you Inspect your HTML with Chrome or Firefox, when your image is displayed, the button div code looks like this:

```
<div id="login_div"><div class="fb-login-button"><a class="fb_button fb_button_medium"><span class="fb_button_text">Login with Facebook</span></a></div></div>
```

However, when it doesn't show, it looks like this:

```
<div id="login_div"><div class="fb-login-button">Login with Facebook</div></div>
```

I can't see all your code, but my guess is that the FB Javascript code is having some timing issues with the code that does the setup of your div.  Thus, your div is not getting properly set, and the CSS can't apply the respective style (background image, background colors).  I can't totally tell what you're doing but it seems you're just doing standard if-logged-in-do-this-else-show-login-button.  Try to simplify your Facebook login checking code to something like:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
if (response.session) {
    fb_user_logged = 1;
    // Do or Show facebook authenticated stuff
} else {
    $("#login_div").html('<div class="fb-login-button"><a class="fb_button fb_button_medium"><span class="fb_button_text">Login with Facebook</span></a></div>');
}
```

});

Also, you should use the [asynchronous version](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) to get around these timing dependencies.

At the very least, you can first get this display logic working consistently before you stuff all your logic back in

Comment: This didn't solve my problem however I appreciate the advice for the login code and will add this into the new update. Thanks!

Comment: Thought I'd add that it did end up being a timing issue, and I would add yours as the accepted answer also if I could, thanks.

Comment: No problem.  I got intermittent results too. It's a timing issue, so you need to simplify your code to remove the synchronous dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Move the script block after the content div.